# AngularJS: Hide the form with one click without showing error message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

This is what my form looks like in the plunker.

[image]

I've added ng-message validation on my email field. To make it more user-friendly I'm showing the error message on blur and to achieve this I used `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`. I also have a `Hide` button to hide the form. So far it works fine.

**Problem:**

1. If I type an invalid email address in the field and click outside, error message shows. But If I type an invalid email and click the `Hide Form` button I want to hide the form instead of showing the error message first.

**N.B.** Strangely sometimes **Hide Form** works as expected but most of the time it does not. and I'm not sure why.

[image]

2. It's optional: Can I hide my error message again if I focus back the input field? I think it'll improve the UX a bit.

Working **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YuBUTFiUiv3cai55ZE7N?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - This is happening because the button is being moved away from the mouse cursor as soon as the text box loses focus, which is causing the click to cancel. Simple fix:

Change

```
ng-click="canceled = true"
```

to

```
ng-mousedown="canceled = true"
```

If you don't want this instant behaviour on mouse down, then you can do something like

```
ng-mousedown="mousedown = true"
ng-mouseup="mousedown = false"
```

and add !mousedown to the ng-if of the help-block.  Or just position the hide button so that it doesn't move when the error block displays. You could use position: absolute, or something like ng-style="{'visibility' : condition ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}" on the help block so it doesn't affect the layout when hidden.

2 - Yes, sure.

In the input element:

```
ng-focus="focused = true"
ng-blur="focused = false"
```

Then in the ng-if of the help-block:

```
ng-if="userForm.email.$touched && !focused"
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OGITYg6Rd0n8998ccxF1?p=preview)